# Form control encapsulation

Tags: vb6, encapsulation

Is there a way (in VB6) to encapsulate a control within a form so that the consumers of the form cannot modify the properties of the control on that form?

e.g If I have a form named `Form1` with a button named `Command1`, how do I prevent consumers (of `Form1`) from doing this:

```
Form1.Command1.Enable = True
```

I rather want to expose a method like `EnableCommand()` and let the method decide whether it is a valid operation to enable the command or not.

Most other languages the control on a form is private by default, how can one make a control `Private` in VB6?

Comment: +1 because I don't understand why the question was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no easy way. In VB.Net you can set the access modifier of the controls in the form designer, but you can't do that in VB6.

In a big application, you can subdivide the logic into separate components (typically DLLs). Then the other components wouldn't have access to the form at all, including its controls.

Comment: An alternative is to put the button on a usercontrol and define your own set of properties.

Comment: Even more the reason to hate this damn language. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: @LukeWage but that user control it self is not encapsulated within the form, so the consumer can just move/hide/[do what ever they like] with the control...

Comment: @FrancoisNel: That is correct. I was under the assumption that it was only a question of enabling / disabling the button control itself. If you also want to encapsulate the user control, go with MarkJ's suggestion and put the whole form into a separate dll.